# How can I filter a TXT file using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, filtering

I have a txt file that displays the following information returned by AutoCAD:

```
; IAcadToolbar: An AutoCAD toolbar

; Property values:

;   Application (RO) = #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadApplication 00d591b4>

;   Count (RO) = 19

;   DockStatus (RO) = 4

;   FloatingRows = 5

;   Height (RO) = AutoCAD: The toolbar is invisible. Please make it visible

;   HelpString = "Draw Toolbar\n    "

;   LargeButtons (RO) = 0

;   left = 1310

;   Name = "Draw"

;   Parent (RO) = #<VLA-OBJECT IAcadToolbars 224a6b04>

;   TagString (RO) = "ID_TbDraw"

;   top = 646

;   Visible = 0

;   Width (RO) = AutoCAD: The toolbar is invisible. Please make it visible

; Methods supported:

;   AddSeparator (1)

;   AddToolbarButton (5)

;   Delete ()

;   Dock (1)

;   Float (3)

;   Item (1)
```

Problem being is that I need to filter it so I am only left with:

```
;   DockStatus (RO) = 4

;   left = 1310

;   Name = "Draw"

;   top = 646

;   Visible = 0
```

They must also remain in the same order:

`;   DockStatus (RO) = 4` always on top followed by
`;   left = 1310` and so on, all other information may be discarded.

Dose anybody know how to do this in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Dim output = New StringBuilder()

' Read the lines from FileName into an array of strings. '
Dim input = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)

For Each line in input

    If line.StartsWith(";   DockStatus (RO) = ") OrElse
       line.StartsWith(";   left = ") OrElse
       line.StartsWith(";   Name = ") OrElse
       line.StartsWith(";   top = ") OrElse
       line.StartsWith(";   Visible = ") Then

       output.AppendLine(line)

    End If

Next
```

Comment: @Frank. Did this answer help? If so you can accept the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq as to why/how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming that you've got a file that you're reading line by line, can't you simply do something like this? (pseudo code only)

```
string result;
foreach line in linesFromFile
{
    if(line.StartsWith("; DockStatus") or 
       line.StartsWith("; Name = "))
    {
        result += line;
    }
}
```

What I've presented is not pretty, but might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to put all values in string and then use splitter 
then filter out the values you need
and sort them in order you need 
 then convert them as required in your output format